# ApnsPHP on Linux

Tags: ios4, apple-push-notifications

I am setting up a push server on Linux. I made it working on Mac OS X easily as the KeyChain helped me a lot.

Is there any hint on generating the .pem of local cert and the Entrust Root Cert on Linux for ApnsPHP (http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great tutorial on how to send push notifications from a PHP script. Pretty much everything to get the script working is covered.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12